# On Android, what happens when my app is backgrounded?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new to Android development. In my project, I have a webview created in the main UI thread. When the app is backgrounded, some content (like the GIF and CSS animation) continue, while a video player is stopped.

Can anyone please point me to a credible source explaining how Android backgrounds and foregrounds an app?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are curious about the behavior of `WebView` when your activity is stopped. That will vary over time, particularly on Android 4.4+, where the implementation of `WebView` is decoupled from the Android version. I doubt that the behavior that you are interested in is documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Murat has the answer in his comment:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem